# How can I get an expired AA battery out of a wireless keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I've just had an Apple Wireless Keyboard returned to me.
[image]

The thing is, it appears the batteries have expires and gone all...crusty. I can take the end off and pull the first battery out, but the other one is pretty firmly stuck in. I've tried scraping a lot of the gunk off with a long, thin object, but I've got nowhere. I've also tried banging it a few times to loosen the battery up, to no luck.

Can I crack this thing open and get the battery out, or do I face an interesting visit to an Apple store?

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me.  i had to use a curved pick to pierce the battery and pull it out.
but it wasn't so simple because not only was the battery swollen, but it was also chemically bonded after the alkali leak. i did eventually get it to work again, it did require some sanding and grinding after.

good luck